# How to setup Jenkins to run one type of jobs exclusively on the host?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 3 types of jobs.
One type of jobs should be started on the host exclusively.
Two other types of jobs could be started on the same host concurrently.

Details are following:
Jobs of type 1 could be started in any quantity per host(for example 3 jobs per host).
Jobs of type 2 could be started only one job per host.
Jobs of 1 and 2 types could be started concurrently on the same host.
Jobs of 1 and 2 types could not be started on the host where job type 3 already was started.
Jobs of type 3 could be started only one job per host and could not be started concurrently with jobs of 1 and 3 types.

Is it possible to configure these requirements using Throttle Concurrent Build plugin or some other plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods I can think of to achieve this. The first one would be to used parameterized trigger builds, using the following plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

The second option would be to trigger the builds using webhooks and working out the logic you need via any language/schedule you choose.